# Values in a header being set to NULL when included after being defined

Tags: c++, sdl, header-files

I'm writing a simple game in C++ using SDL. I have written a more complicated game before, but it was in one source file consisting of 4000+ lines of code.

My problem is that variables seem to be being reset at the end of the .cpp file they are defined in.

In Declarations.cpp (Amongst other things)

```
bool CheckFiles()
{
    SDL_Surface *Background = LoadImage("Resources/Images/Background.png");
    SDL_Surface *Character1 = LoadImage("Resources/Images/Character.png");
    SDL_Surface *MenuBackground = LoadImage("Resources/Images/MenuBackground.png");
    TTF_Font *EightBitLimit = TTF_OpenFont("Resources/Fonts/EightBitLimit.ttf",16);
    TTF_Font *KarmaFuture = TTF_OpenFont("Resources/Fonts/KarmaFuture.ttf",16);
    TTF_Font *EightBitLimitSmall = TTF_OpenFont("Resources/Fonts/EightBitLimit.ttf",9);
    SDL_Surface *Message1 = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *Message2 = NULL;

    if (Background == NULL) return false;
    if (Character1 == NULL) return false;
    if (MenuBackground == NULL) return false;
    if (EightBitLimit == NULL) return false;
    if (KarmaFuture == NULL) return false;
    if (EightBitLimitSmall == NULL) return false; //Breakpoint here, everything has loaded fine
    return true;
}
```

In Menu.cpp

```
#include"Declarations.h"
#include"Menu.h"

void Menu()
{
    while (Quit == false && State == MENU)
    {
        CheckFiles();
        ApplySurface(0,0,MenuBackground,Screen); //Gives an access violation as all surfaces and fonts have became NULL
        Message1 = TTF_RenderText_Solid(KarmaFuture,"Tripping Octo Dangerzone",White);
```

My header files are properly guarded. Variables and functions are declared like so:

```
extern TTF_Font *KarmaFuture;
extern bool CheckFiles();
```

My main.cpp file:

```
#include"Declarations.h"
#include"Menu.h"
#include"Game.h"

int main (int argc, char* argv [])
{
    if (Init() == false) return -1;
    if (CheckFiles() == false) return -1; //Everything is initialized and loaded properly
    while (Quit == false)
    {
        switch(State)
            {
    case MENU:
        Menu();
        break;
    case GAME:
        Game();
        break;
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

This is my first time working with header files, so sorry if my mistake is glaringly obvious. Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: you are aware, that your pointers from `bool CheckFiles()` run out of scope ( function return ) and arent accessable in main ( or wherever ) correctly? Yes, they will still allocate the memory, but you dont get that info into main ( or your class ), as you *locally* declared them in the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not checking the same variable.

The

```
SDL_Surface *MenuBackground = LoadImage("Resources/Images/MenuBackground.png");
```

line in `CheckFiles()` declares a *local* variable called `MenuBackground`. This variable has nothing to do with any other variable of the same name at any other location in your program (except the scope that line is in, and any child-scopes).

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a really basic mistake. I loaded them outside of the function and it worked fine. Silly me.